# How to pass a selector function as a paramater in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uikit

I have a standard View Controller that has the following selector:

```
@objc func finished() {
    //Do Something here
}
```

I have an outside class called ButtonFactory that looks something like this:

```
class ButtonFactory {
    static let shared = ButttonFactory()

    func createButton(functionParameter: () -> Void ) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(functionParameter), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    } 

}
```

In my view controller I call createButton like this:

```
ButtonFactory.shared.createButton(functionParamter: self.finished)
```

However the above code does not compile saying: Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to parameter 'functionParameter'.

**Is it possible to pass a selector function as a parameter in Swift 5?**

Comment: Have a look at [how other people did it](https://github.com/muizidn/eventclosure). It might help.

Comment: This does not seem to be a SwiftUI question, but rather a UIKit question....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your function using a Selector:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @objc func finished() {
        //Do Something here
    }
}
```

---

```
class ButtonFactory {
    static let shared = ButtonFactory()
    func createButton(_ action: Selector) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }
}
```

---

```
let button = ButtonFactory.shared.createButton(#selector(ViewController.finished))
```

---

Note that you should pass the view controller instance as well to your method instead of setting the target to your ButtonFactory shared instance.